# "How to calculate the number of cells that have changed out of a total"

Tags: vba

I am building a program that measures the metrics of our company actions and progress and I am having trouble with a particular part. I am doing this in VBA, and I want to perform the following actions:

```
1. Compare a range on two spreadsheets to find mismatches.
2. Calculate (not format) how many cells are different and then send that 
   resultant value a target cell on another spreadsheet in the workbook.
   EX: If 2 out of 10 cells do not match then the target cell 
       value should be 2
3. Replicate this process for about 6 other parameters in the workbook 
   (That is the easy part I think).
```

I have used/given the following VBA functions to try to get a resultant:
WorksheetFunction.sum
Evaulate(SumProduct)

I do not believe the problem is in the compare code itself (As I have just borrowed some internet examples I have seen.) But in the function that occurs after the 'Else' statement. The code runs and debugs fine, however no answer is produced. The code is below, make the assumptions that variables are declared (for space purposes).

```
Worksheets("Generalized Report").Activate
strRangeToCheck = "F2:F10000" 'Range can change depending on amount of data on sheets'

varSheetA = Worksheets("Contract").Range(strRangeToCheck)
varSheetB = Worksheets("As Built").Range(strRangeToCheck)

'Loop thru and do the comparison cell by cell via an array
For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
    For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
        If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
            ' Cells are identical.
            ' Do nothing.
        Else
            ' Cells are different.

            ' Calculate how many cells are different
            Worksheet("Generalized Report").Activate
            Worksheet("Generalized Report").Range("A8") = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--('Contract'!F2:F10000<>'As Built'!F2:F10000)")
```

In this particular case I am expecting a value of 0 (As this is test data), but the value should equal the number of cells that are different. The following 3 things occur with my code based on my adjustments:

1. No answer given
2. `#Value!` error
3. For already assigned

Thanks for your time.

Comment: you are missing a `)` at the end of your SUMPRODUCT: `Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--('Contract'!F2:F10000<>'As Built'!F2:F10000))")`

Comment: Hi Scott, I added the ) and the function still did not work as expected. Am I missing anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I would count the differences in VBA instead of trying to use the SUMPRODUCT formula:

```
Dim DifferenceCount as Long
Worksheets("Generalized Report").Activate
strRangeToCheck = "F2:F10000" 'Range can change depending on amount of data on sheets'

varSheetA = Worksheets("Contract").Range(strRangeToCheck)
varSheetB = Worksheets("As Built").Range(strRangeToCheck)

'Loop thru and do the comparison cell by cell via an array
For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
    For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
        If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
            ' Cells are identical.
            ' Do nothing.
        Else
            ' Cells are different.
            DifferenceCount = DifferenceCount + 1
        End If
    Next iCol
Next iRow
Worksheet("Generalized Report").Range("A8") = DifferenceCount
```

**Edit**

When I think about it there are two other alternatives using your formula...

Firstly your whole macro could just be

```
Worksheet("Generalized Report").Range("A8") = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--('Contract'!F2:F10000<>'As Built'!F2:F10000)")
```

This would put the formula result in A8.

The second alternative is just to use the formula `=SUMPRODUCT(--('Contract'!F2:F10000<>'As Built'!F2:F10000)` straight in A8.

The code in your question is evaluating the formula multiple times in the two loops if you have multiple cells that don't match.  This is unnecessary and could be very slow for a large/complex spreadsheet.

Comment: What ended up happening was the code was correct, it was my own tiredness of looking at the formula. I needed some fresh eyes to see it from and realized that because the data matched, it did exactly what it should have. However the different count approach might warrant another look at the formula overall for convenience. Thank you!

Comment: @TDB I have added to my answer to explain why I wouldn't use the formula the way you have in your question and to give you some extra options.